# How is Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::orderRand() optimized?

Tags: collection, sql, sorting, random

Magento comes with a method to randomly "order" collections:

```
$collection->getSelect()->orderRand();
```

It takes an optional parameter `$field`, that is eventually used in `Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql::orderRand()`:

```
/**
 * Adds order by random to select object
 * Possible using integer field for optimization
 *
 * @param Varien_Db_Select $select
 * @param string $field
 * @return Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql
 */
public function orderRand(Varien_Db_Select $select, $field = null)
{
    if ($field !== null) {
        $expression = new Zend_Db_Expr(sprintf('RAND() * %s', $this->quoteIdentifier($field)));
        $select->columns(array('mage_rand' => $expression));
        $spec = new Zend_Db_Expr('mage_rand');
    } else {
        $spec = new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()');
    }
    $select->order($spec);

    return $this;
}
```

### My question is

How is `RAND() * integer_column` an optimization in comparison to `RAND()` and isn't the result skewed in favor of larger `integer_column` values? Is there a better way to retrieve random results using Magento collections? Ordering by `RAND()` gets expensive for large tables.

Comment: May help with your question: http://jan.kneschke.de/projects/mysql/order-by-rand/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. `RAND()` produces a value between `0` and `1`, therefore produces `RAND() * some_value` a value between 0 and `some_value`.

I would interpret the term "optimization" in this context as weighting.

Comment: Now it makes sense, somewhat. Core Dev 1 mixes up the words, core dev 2 passes entity_id for random product collection in faith for optimized query...